# Is there a way in powershell to easily signal when a long-running command finished (e.g. file move command)

Tags: powershell

I've started a file move command at CMD.EXE and wait minutes and hours for completion of my administrative transfer of TBs of data. To get a signal when it's finished, it would be great to get a signal somehow after the command finished

What I've got:

1. window with CMD.EXE> MOVE G:*.* T:
2. window with powershell

I already found some helpful code to identify the process

```
Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTitle -like "*move*"} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize
```

which shows something like

```
PS L:\srvcl01> Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTitle -like "*move*"} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize

  Id Name MainWindowTitle
  -- ---- ---------------
2820 cmd  Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe - move l:srvcl01_hdd2_data.vhdx .
```

Now it just needs to wait for disappearing of this main window title and then send an e-mail or system sound

Comment: not supported on some remote desktop instances, but maybe helpful in many cases: play system's asterisk sound: ([System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk).Play()

Comment: I would recommend running `robocopy` instead which can display percentage progress as it runs. When it completes you can send an email message (if you have an available SMTP server).

Comment: robocopy is not always available and it should be usable with system tools only

Comment: email send command could like like e.g. (for anonymous send): Send-MailMessage -to "me.myself@company.com" -from "admin-server123@company.com" -Subject "DONE: File copy/move task finished" -body "Finished :-)" -SmtpServer smtp.company.local -Port 2567

Comment: I don't always have my sound up so I usually open the CD drive when a long script ends.

Comment: "`robocopy` is not always available" - not correct; `robocopy` is built into the Windows OS (for sure in Windows 7/Server 2012 R2; maybe even in Vista/Server 2012).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart in fact, you're right! sorry for my confusion!

Comment: Robocopy has been a part of the base install since Vista/Server 2008.  In Windows XP it was a separate download, and in Server 2003/Server 2003 R2 it was a part of the Resource Kit.

Answer (score 1):

> Now it just needs to wait for disappearing of this main window title and then send an e-mail or system sound

```
While (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle -like '*move*'}) { }

[Console]::Beep(1000,1000)
#OR
Send-MailMessage ...
```

Once the process ends, the loop will end and fall through to the options below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself in parallel - but thanks to @TheIncorrigible1 who already provided a first solution

This is now my code - which waits a few seconds between each interval (reduces CPU load):

```
while (@(Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle -like "*move*"}).length -gt 0){
   Start-Sleep -s 15
}; Send-MailMessage -to "me.myself@company.com" -from "admin-server123@company.com" -Subject "DONE: File copy/move task finished" -body "Finished :-)" -SmtpServer smtp.company.local -Port 2567
```

And by the way: my file move job finished after approx. 6 hours successfully ;-)

Comment: You should use `.Count`